# Comment name mention autofill box sits above "new contributor" banner

Tags: bug, comments, design

I just noticed that the mention autofill box thing floats higher than it normally would if there's a "new contributor" banner above the comment box.

I only realised you can press tab to complete the name a few months ago, and in the years before that I always just clicked the box, so I sometimes still click the box out of habit. It feels awkward to click it when it randomly sits in a different spot.

[image: nearly forgot the freehand red circle]

Comment: Where would you suggest putting it if not there?

Comment: @Laurel Where it goes normally? It's an overlay, it should overlay.